# Can I give prizes based on sharing a WebGL game link on Facebook?

Tags: unity, unity-webgl

I made a share to Facebook link for my WebGL Unity game and depending on when you share you get extra points. This is tied to a button which once pressed opens a new page to Facebook for sharing the link but at the moment when you press the button you get the extra points either way.

Is there a way to actually know when the content has been shared or not?

Answer (score 1):

**You are not allowed to reward users for sharing**, since 2014, because it made for a completely awful experience for all of their friends. Before this rule, if you had a lot of gamer friends, all you'd ever see in your feed was these spammy incentivized share posts.

See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/77969/is-rewarding-users-for-sharing-using-facebook-or-twitter-breaking-the-tos

Answer (score 0):

1. Ask the player for their social media handle within your application
2. Open the window where they can share the content
3. Have the game contact a server you control
4. Have the server look up their social media account and confirm that they indeed shared the content

Comment: i see , maybe any guides in doing so? or shoud i google each part?!

Comment: Although this sounds like a hassle, in general anything that requires validation *must* have a server side component. The reason is that server code is not accessible to the end user but client code (in this case browser code on FB) is and can be "tweaked" to do things you don't want it to do. If you are not familiar with "backend" code then this might not be an easy-peasy implementation though.

Comment: well yeah you right but i do want to learn it so i got to start somewhere!

Comment: Then you are in luck. Doing backend development is a central part of creating *web applications* which is **the** buzziest concept in the programming world since 2010 so there are almost *infinite* resources to go around. I suggest you choose an easy language such as Python, Javascript or PHP and search for "server side development using ...". This is a big concept (although your needs are only a fraction of it) so this isn't the place to discuss it in depth.

Comment: @Philipp You are not allowed to reward users for sharing. Also, with all of the privacy changes it might not even be possible to check whether a specific user has shared something these days.