# Is it allowed by social platforms to promote a game in exchange for in-game currency?

Tags: unity, social

I have a mobile game that uses a a hint system.

If the user needs help to solve a puzzle they can get a hint by watching an ad. I'm interested in offering some hints, let's say 5, if the user presses a Facebook/Twitter button and posts some predefined text on those platforms - something like "I've been playing X game, check it out".

I haven't seen many games that have something like this. For those more familiar with App Store and Play Store publishing guidelines, is there anything against such behaviour?

Comment: [You may be interested in this recent answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/189822/39518) or [This past Q&A on a related StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/77969)

Comment: As a side note, depending on the type of your game _"If the user needs help to solve a puzzle, they can get a hint by"_ .... asking Google.